# Unable to interact with Tableau Report with Tableau Public

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau, and I created a basic web page adding in the Tableau JavaScript API for Tableau Public.

The web page runs, and I can see the report, but I am unable to interact with report. The report has some checkboxes which alter the report when checked. If run the report URL itself in the browser on its own it will load the report and I can interact with it, but when using in a web page - nope! I ran the JavaScript Console, and it gave these errors:

GET http://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/api/auth/author?&no_cache=1400773479254 404 (Not Found) angular.js:7772
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.min.js:3
Attr.specified is deprecated. Its value is always true. clientweb.xd.js:16

Does this mean there is something wrong with Tableau?

Comment: Could you use Pastebin to upload your web page so that it can be tested please?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok, I have fixed it by changing the way I wrote the JS.